# SQL Query binary data to generate text?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Actually, I'm not sure what title this question should be.

I have a table, which has 1 column. The data is a binary data. Each bit maps to 1 text string. Now, I have a number X. How can I get the text string that number M represents?

For example,

```
bit0 maps: bit0;
bit1 maps: bit1;
bit2 maps: bit2;
bit3 maps: bit3;
....
bit7 maps: bit7;
```

Now, I have number X = 6, which = 4+2. I want to get the text string 'bit2,bit1'.

If we can not generate 'bit2,bit1', can we generate multiple rows one has 'bit2' and one has 'bit1' (or more rows if the binary data has more 1s)?

Is it possible to do this in a SQL query without using stored procedure?

thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do with storing bytes separately in rows? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Why the requirement not to use a stored procedure? That is a rather strange requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that "no stored procedure" really means "in a single query".  You can use the `STUFF`/`XML PATH` approach to do this fairly easily.  I don't know your table structure so you'll have to generalize this for your data source, but it should produce the results you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @value int = 6

SELECT STUFF(
  (SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (@value & 128) > 0 THEN ',bit7' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN (@value & 64) > 0 THEN ',bit6' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN (@value & 32) > 0 THEN ',bit5' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN (@value & 16) > 0 THEN ',bit4' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN (@value & 8) > 0 THEN ',bit3' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN (@value & 4) > 0 THEN ',bit2' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN (@value & 2) > 0 THEN ',bit1' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN (@value & 1) > 0 THEN ',bit0' ELSE '' END
FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```